# How to calculate the integration $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(2-\cos{x})^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Given that 
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{2-\cos{x}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}
$$

How to calculate the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(2-\cos{x})^2}
$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It is the same question, so yes.

Comment: It's not _exactly_ the same, but some of the answers for the earlier question ought to be helpful...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have
$$
\mathcal{I}(a)=\int_0^{\large\pi} \frac{d\theta}{a-\cos\theta}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}},
$$
then differentiating both the sides with respect to $a$, you will obtain
$$
\mathcal{I}'(a)=\int_0^{\large\pi} \frac{d\theta}{(a-\cos\theta)^2}=\frac{a\pi}{(a^2-1)^{\large\frac32}}.
$$

Comment: Got it, thanks!